# Browser incompatiblity with jQuery, IE and FF

Tags: jquery, filter, cross-browser, html-select

I have some simple jQuery which lets a user click a link in an `LI` to filter on options in a select list.  It functions fully in FF, but only partially in Chrome or IE.  I'm not getting any errors in the Console(s). The issue is that the class update works in Chrome and IE, but not the filtering.

I must be on the right track since it's working in FF, but I assume I'm missing a concept here.  I greatly appreciate your input.

jQuery:

> Summary: get id of clicked li, update the li class, use that id value
>   to only show select list options with that value as the title.

```
$("ul#mission-list li").click(function(){
    var currMission = this.id;
    $("li.here").removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('here');
    $("#selBox1").children('option').hide();
    if (currMission != 'all') {
        $("#selBox1").children("option[title^=" + currMission + "]").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#selBox1").children('option').show();
    }
});
```

HTML

The selection list is simply this:

```
<ul id="mission-list">
    <li id="all" class="here"><a href="javascript:void(0);">All</a></li>
    <li id="group1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Group 1</a></li>
    <li id="group2"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Group 2</a></li>
    <li id="group3"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Group 3</a></li>
</ul>

And when the select options get rendered from the query, it's something like this (simplified down here).  This is the list that should be filtered in the display as a result of clicking the li option above:
<select multiple="multiple" id="selBox1">
    <option value="12" title="group1">Mission 1</option>
    <option value="34" title="group2">Mission 2</option>
    <option value="45" title="group2">Mission 3</option>
    <option value="78" title="group3">Mission 3</option>
    <option value="90" title="group3">Mission 3</option>
</select>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `ul#mission-list` is over-specific, `#mission-list` is unique enough.

Comment: try javascript:return false; instead of void(0)

Comment: and why do you use the ^= selector and not simply the = one?

Comment: Hi Paolo.  Essentially because I do what I'm told.  :)  JSLint told me to use the more specific selector.  Another page I found suggested void(0) over return false.  And ^= because an example similar to what I was trying to do used it.  But I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are triyng to "display: none" on a multiple select box which will not work.  Instead you must set to visible: hidden.  But the issue with this is that the values will still be there so you may have to rethink and recreate the multiple select box by the values instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/UBdhn/1

Javascript

```
$("ul#mission-list li").click(function(){
    var currMission = this.id;
    console.log(this.id);
    $("li.here").removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('here');
    console.log($("#selBox1").children());
    $("#selBox1").children().css("visibility", "hidden");
    if (currMission != 'all') {
        $("#selBox1").children("option[title^=" + currMission + "]").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else {
        $("#selBox1").children('option').css("visibility", "visible");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that, Chad.  Very helpful information.  I agree - I think this is going to involve dynamically recreating the multiple select box instead.  I'll head in that direction.  I appreciate you helping to narrow down the options.